# R caret Error: Something is wrong; all the Accuracy metric values are missing:

Tags: r, r-caret

I'm trying to apply stacking on my dataset but here I am.

```
# Load library
library(DJL)
library(caret)
library(caretEnsemble)

# Load data and format the target attribute to avoid clutters
df <- dataset.engine.2015[, -c(1, 2)]
levels(df$Type) <- list(NA.D = "NA-D", NA.P = "NA-P", SC.P = "SC-P", TC.D = "TC-D", TC.P = "TC-P")

# Run
st.methods <- c("lda", "rpart", "glm", "knn", "svmRadial")
st.control <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 5, repeats = 3, 
                           savePredictions = T, classProbs = T)
st.models  <- caretList(Type ~., data = df, trControl = st.control, methodList = st.methods)
```

Then I get this:

```
Something is wrong; all the Accuracy metric values are missing:
    Accuracy       Kappa    
 Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA  
 1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA  
 Median : NA   Median : NA  
 Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN  
 3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA  
 Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA  
 NA's   :1     NA's   :1    
Error: Stopping
In addition: There were 18 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

Can anyone help me to fix this error?

Comment: Could you try to make your example [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), else any advice would be mere speculation.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to load the package "caretEnsemble". Now, you can reproduce my error. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Without a few observations from your input dataset `dataset.engine.2015`, your example is not reproducible. If your dataset is proprietary you can use options mentioned in first comment to anonymize it. Essentially, create a small test dataset on which you receive the error and post the output of `dput(DF)` where `DF` is the test dataset.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "not reproducible". The dataset (dataset.engine.2015) is accompanied with the package "DJL" so I believe you can simply implement my code to load it and reproduce my issue. Please advise if this is not what you asked.

Comment: I am sorry,please excuse my unfamiliarity with `DJL` package and my assumption that `dataset.engine.2015` is a user-defined dataset.

Answer (score 3):

The `glm` model cannot be used for predicting categorical dependent variables with more than two categories. Try to delete `glm` from `st.methods` or substitute `glm` with, for example, `multinom`, `gbm`, `randomForest`.

Here are two useful experiment. In the first we consider only `glm`:

```
rm(list=ls())
library(DJL)
library(caret)
library(caretEnsemble)  
df <- dataset.engine.2015[, -c(1, 2)]
levels(df$Type) <- list(NA.D = "NA-D", NA.P = "NA-P", SC.P = "SC-P", TC.D = "TC-D", TC.P = "TC-P")

st.control <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 5, repeats = 3, 
                           savePredictions = T, classProbs = T)

st.methods <- c("glm")
st.models  <- caretList(Type ~., data = df, trControl = st.control, methodList = st.methods)
```

Here is the error message:

```
Something is wrong; all the Accuracy metric values are missing:
    Accuracy       Kappa    
 Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA  
 1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA  
 Median : NA   Median : NA  
 Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN  
 3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA  
 Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA  
 NA's   :1     NA's   :1    
Error in train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) : Stopping
Inoltre: There were 18 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

Now we substitute `glm` with `multinom`:

```
st.methods <- c("multinom")
st.models  <- caretList(Type ~., data = df, trControl = st.control, methodList = st.methods)
print(st.models)
```

The output is:

```
$multinom
Penalized Multinomial Regression 

1206 samples
   5 predictor
   5 classes: 'NA.D', 'NA.P', 'SC.P', 'TC.D', 'TC.P' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (5 fold, repeated 3 times) 
Summary of sample sizes: 964, 965, 965, 965, 965, 964, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  decay  Accuracy   Kappa    
  0e+00  0.9306411  0.8518294
  1e-04  0.9300901  0.8506964
  1e-01  0.9328507  0.8564466

Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using  the largest value.
The final value used for the model was decay = 0.1.
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! It works now but unfortunately caretEnsemble package doesn't provide stacking for multi-class (>2) problems: it returns "Not yet implemented for multiclass problems" when I try to create an ensemble solution using caretStack function. I wish I had known this earlier! I may have to find another package to complete this task. Please comment if anyone knows better options in R.